# Unable to import dependency installed from git in setup.py

Tags: python

I am trying to use setup.py to install a Python package that is kept in a git repository, which we'll call `my_dependency`. In `my_package`, I have a setup.py file with:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        ...
        'my_dependency=VERSION'
    ],
    dependency_links=['git+https://...my_dependency.git#egg=my_dependency-VERSION',]
)
```

When I run my setup file (`python setup.py develop`), the dependency appears to install; it shows up as `my_dependency==VERSION` when I run `pip freeze`. However, when I start a python session and call `import my_dependency`, I get `ImportError: No module named my_dependency`.

I don't know if this is possibly the source of the problem, but when running setup.py, I get a warning:

```
Processing dependencies for my_package==0.1
Searching for my_dependency==VERSION
Doing git clone from https://.../my_dependency.git to /var/folders/.../.../T/easy_install-_rWjyp/my_dependency.git
Best match: my_dependency VERSION
Processing my_dependency.git
Writing /var/folders/.../my_dependency.git/setup.cfg
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/.../my_dependency.git/egg-dist-tmp-UMiNdL
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

Copying my_dependency-VERSION-py2.7.egg to /.../my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding my_dependency VERSION to easy-install.pth file
```

However, I am able to use the package if I install it through pip, like this: `pip install -e git+https://.../my_dependency.git#egg=my_dependency-VERSION`

For reference, the dependency package structure looks like this:

```
my_dependency/
    my_dependency/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

And its setup.py contains this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_dependency',
    version='VERSION',
    description='...',
    author='...',
    url='https://...',
    license='MIT',
    install_requires=[
        'numpy',
    ],

    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was (in retrospect) pretty silly. My dependency package was missing this line in its setup.py:

```
packages=['my_dependency'],
```

That meant the package was correctly building and installing, but it wasn't actually including the code in the package. This became apparent when I looked at the SOURCES.txt in the egg-info: it didn't include any of the Python source files in the package.